# connection:didReceiveResponse: from NSURLConnectionDelegate never fired

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue, uiprogressview

I'm trying to get UIProgressView, NSURLConnection, NSOperation and NSOperationQueue working together.
Here is the code: http://pastie.org/4080576

**Problem:**
`connection:DidReceiveData:` never called: execution going immediately to `-start()`, through `-main()`, then to `-connection:DidReceiveResponse:`, back to `-main()` (sometimes), and finally to `-connectionDidFinishDownloading:destinationURL:`.

When I trying to download picture from this link:
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/41/Kharkov_picture_1787.jpg

I get this output:

> 2012-06-13 19:43:06.189 downloadingFilesInOpQueue[5070:f803] Received
>   response:  2012-06-13 19:43:06.190
>   downloadingFilesInOpQueue[5070:f803] Filesize is: 3075638 Suggested
>   filename is: Kharkov_picture_1787.jpg 2012-06-13 19:43:12.476
>   downloadingFilesInOpQueue[5070:f803] Finished downloading. Received 0
>   bytes

Also, I can't figure out where `connection:didReceiveResponse:` belong:
NSURLConnectionDelegate or NSURLConnectionDataDelegate.

P.S. If there some style issues, I would glad to hear about them. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suspect your "busy" while-loops are consuming the underlying run-loop's execution and choking out the NSURLConnection from being able to handle data as it arrives.

Looking at your pastie.org code, here's your primary culprits:

```
while (![self isFinished]) {
    ...
    while ([self fileSize] == 0) {}
    while ([self receivedDataLength] == 0) {}
    ...
}
```

Busy loops like this should almost never be used in iOS.  iOS programming is largely event-driven, especially NSURLConnection.  Instead, update your `UIProgressView` in response to `connection:DidReceiveData:` etc.

Honestly, coding your own NSURLConnection handlers is kind of a messy pain.  I strongly recommend you look into using an open-source library that handles some of the difficulties. Here's two decent ones to check out:

1. https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking
2. https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request

Comment: Than you very much, my thoughts was the same.
I will refactor out these loops, but I can't use such an external libraries.
Also, I know about webkit-way to do this, but it is also isn't my way.
Thank you once again.

Comment: Btw, I'll just didn't want to stretch one task over whole program. In my mind, one task should be in one place, but I don't see such an exit from this situation.
If you see, tell me please.